# Items in my Array are undefined even tho there is data in it

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am dynamically assigning an Array by Info's from a HTTP Request. I then try to generate something from data in that Array - and I console.log'd the Array so I know there is data in it. Yet while looping over it every key is undefined.

Basically, every item I get back from the REST Server has an ID marking that they belong together in some way. I'll call that "SlotID" for now.

I'll try to keep it very simple. So here are some cut-outs.

```js
let items = new Array(23); // The highest "SlotID" can be 22, and 0 isn't used.
fetch(URI)
.then(results => {
    return results.json();
}).then(data => {
    for (var itemKey in data.Results) {
        var item = data.Results[itemKey]; // This is all just the fetch.
        if (items[item.SlotID] != null) { // I'm creating a new Array for each SlotID here, and if that array is already created I'm pushing to it.
            items[item.SlotID].push(item);
          } else {
            items[item.SlotID] = [item];
          }
        }
    }
});
```

This (for now with a test call) fills items[1]. I confirmed an array being present via console.log(items); which outputs:

(23) […]
​
1: (2) […]
​​
0: Object { BaseParamValue0: 19, BaseParamValue1: 21, BaseParamValue2: 23, … }
​​
1: Object { BaseParamValue0: 10, BaseParamValue1: 10, BaseParamValue2: 17, … }
​​
length: 2
​​
: Array []
​
length: 23
​
: [

So I basically have an Array of Arrays of Objects now.

```js
      for (var i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
        console.log(i + " " + items[i]);
      }
```

However, this outputs 1 as undefined, console.log(items[1]) also outputs undefined. Why?

Comment: What is your output of data? Can you dump it's contents?

Comment: Fetch takes time to execute. Your for is executed probably before the fetch did't finish executing

Comment: It's an Object that has a Pagination object and a Results array. As said the items array has the value I would expect.

Here's a pastebin of the JSON Data I'm getting back. https://pastebin.com/WUdw60N7

Comment: @VamshiGudipati That might be the case, I'll check. Ironically, I've wrote both logging the contents of items and the for loop outside of .then(); - logging returns proper data so that might have confused me.

It's working, thanks alot. If you write that as an Answer I'll mark it.